# PDFsharp - Watermark at bottom of landscape page

Tags: .net, vb.net, pdf, watermark, pdfsharp

I am using PDFsharp to try to add some text at the bottom of a landscape PDF page but it always offsets vertically, the bigger I make the text the closer to the bottom of the page it gets but I want to use size 20 font. If I use a loop to work out the biggest possible size the watermark sits perfectly at the bottom on the page. I have tried many different ways but can't workout what I'm doing wrong..

```
   For Each Page As PdfPage In PDF.Pages
            Dim Graphics As XGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(Page, XGraphicsPdfPageOptions.Append)
            Dim FontSize As Integer = 20
            Dim Font As New XFont("Arial", FontSize, XFontStyle.Bold)
            Dim WaterMarkSize As XSize = Graphics.MeasureString(Watermark, Font)
            Dim Brush As New XSolidBrush(XColor.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0))

            If Page.Orientation = PdfSharp.PageOrientation.Portrait Then
                Graphics.DrawString(Watermark, Font, Brush, New XRect(0, Page.Height, Page.Width, 0), XStringFormats.BottomCenter)
            Else
                Page.Orientation = PageOrientation.Portrait
                Graphics.TranslateTransform(Page.Width.Value / 2, Page.Height.Value / 2)
                Graphics.RotateTransform(90)
                Graphics.TranslateTransform(-Page.Width.Value / 2, -Page.Height.Value / 2)

                Dim Format As New XStringFormat()
                Format.Alignment = XStringAlignment.Near
                Format.LineAlignment = XLineAlignment.Near
                Graphics.DrawString(Watermark, Font, Brush, New XPoint((Page.Width.Value - WaterMarkSize.Width) / 2, Page.Width.Value), Format)
            End If
    Next
```

Result.....
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Why does it set `Page.Orientation = PageOrientation.Portrait` for *landscape* pages?

Comment: I saw this on another post, https://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=333 , otherwise the Watermark is added at the wrong rotation

Comment: Ah, I see. But if you look at woody3k's reply a little bit later, it seems to also need `page.Rotate = 0`, and then they go on to explain what goes wrong and a need to "set [...] the current PageSize value for the landscape pages to be saved correctly."

Comment: Yes, setting the page.Rotate to 0 leaves the end result in portrait which isn't what i want, i added the function to set the PageSize at various different points in the code but it doesn't affect the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

The Y co-ordinate in your `DrawString` call should be based on `page.Height` and not `page.Width`.

You have to use a different `LineAlignment` if you use `page.Width` without adjustment for the font height.

Comment: Hi, i did try this but using the page.Height (which would be logical) but it then seems to put the watermark off the page

Comment: You have to set a proper LineAlignment to have the text above the point you specify. The text is invisible if it goes below the point you specify.

Comment: I understand, but if i use page.height as the Y co-ordinate then whatever i set the line alignment the watermark is off the page.